# Maintaining Aspect Ratio of an Image in a Div with 'Overflow: Hidden' Property

Tags: html, css, sass

I am currently developing a profile page inspired by the layout of Facebook's profile section, specifically the combination of the banner and profile image. My implementation works well on desktop resolutions, but I am encountering issues when resizing the browser window.\

**Issue:**

As the page width decreases, I'm facing two main problems:

**Overflow Handling**: When the page hits the `<a>` boundaries, the banner image begins to fill the element.
**Responsive Scaling**: As I continue to decrease the width, the banner image starts to shrink, but not in the way I intended.\

**Goal:**

I want to achieve two things:

Keep the banner image overflowing the `<a>` element, regardless of the page size.
Ensure the banner image scales down smoothly and responsively as the page width decreases keeping the overflow as well.

**What I've Tried:**

I've attempted various CSS strategies for responsiveness and overflow handling, such as using max-width, overflow, flex-shrink: 0, but haven't achieved the desired result.
Here's my css:

```
.profileHeader{
    @apply w-full h-full flex justify-center items-stretch flex-nowrap shrink-0;

    & > .container{
        @apply w-full h-full flex min-w-0 flex-col shrink grow basis-0 max-w-full relative overflow-hidden;
        & > .container__background{
            @apply w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center z-0 absolute;
            & > img{
                @apply w-full aspect-video bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center blur-2xl grayscale-[60%] ;
            }
        }
        & > .container__content{
            @apply w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center flex-col z-10;

            & > .content__cover{
                @apply max-w-[1450px]  overflow-hidden relative flex justify-center items-center z-10;

                & > .cover__link{
                    @apply grid max-h-[450px] rounded-b-lg relative h-full;
                    & > img{
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        @apply object-cover;
                    }
                }
            }
            & > .content__header{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my actual code

```
<section className={styles.profileHeader}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.container__background}>
                    <Img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/842711/pexels-photo-842711.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-christian-heitz-842711.jpg&fm=jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.container__content}>
                    <div className={styles.content__cover}>
                        <Link to="#" className={styles.cover__link}>
                            <Img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/842711/pexels-photo-842711.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-christian-heitz-842711.jpg&fm=jpg' /> // here is the problem
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.content__header}>
                            <Img className="aspect-square w-40 h-40 rounded-full border-[4px] border-[#242526]" src="/src/assets/profile.jpg"/> 
                            <h1 className="text-8xl font-bold"> <span className="text-[#F8F8F2]">Person Name</span></h1>
                            <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold"><span className="text-[#8BE9FD]">22 common friends</span></h2>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**Question**:

How can I modify my CSS to keep the banner image within its boundaries and ensure it scales down properly as the page size decreases?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the background image as an Img tag in the HTML I'd apply it to a pseudo element of your div with the class name "container__background" using css `background-image: url()`, and then add the following properties .

`background-size: cover`: determines which ratio is most important by seeing if the image is in portrait or landscape mode.

- background-size: cover
- background-position: center
- background-repeat: no-repeat
- padding-bottom: (whatever percentage value you want)

What's important here is the `padding-bottom`. Because padding is relative to the width, you can utilize that to fill up vertical space.

Here's a codesandbox example that has a responsive image that keeps its aspect-ratio. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cocky-dhawan-77vrw6?file=%2Fstyles.css%3A6%2C1-7%2C1

Comment: I don't think that is the best approach, because in my case, the background is dynamic, and as far as i know, i can't use in `background-image` a `--variable`, and it's not even aesthetic. Thank you tho!